# Meaning of "with a tilt of 97.77 degrees - possibly the result of collision"?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of "with a tilt of 97.77 degrees - possibly the result of collision" ?
(Source : https://solarsystem.nasa.gov/planets/uranus/in-depth/ )

> Uranus is the only planet whose equator is nearly at a right angle to
> its orbit, ***with a tilt of 97.77 degrees—possibly the result of a
> collision*** with an Earth-sized object long ago. This unique tilt
> causes the most extreme seasons in the solar system.

Does "with a tilt of 97.77 degrees - possibly the result of collision" mean " Uranus has a tilt of 97.77 degrees which is possibly the result of a collision with an Earth-sized object" ?

Does " - possibly" mean "which is possibly" ?

Comment: Yes to both questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part does mean that Uranus has a tilt of 97.77 degrees which is possibly the result of a collision with an Earth-sized object

so the phrase starting possibly is a reduced relative clause. "Possibly" does mean "which is possibly".